# How to get a embed from a message in Discord.js v14

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im getting a message that got reacted with a emoji, and want to send it in another channel, but I cant get the embed information from that message `reaction.message.embeds` is empty.

Do I need to set some intents to be able to read that data? Like `GatewayIntentsBits.MessageContent` for messages

Want to re-send a message with embed to another channel

[EDIT]
When I do some weird shit: `reaction.message.channel.messages.fetch(reaction.message.id)` the `embeds` tag seems to work, is there any way or reason for that? Or should I use this weird way, can someone explain to me why the first example doesnt work?

Answer (score 0):

In regards of the Intents:

This property requires the GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent privileged intent in a guild for messages that do not mention the client. (https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds)

The return is an Array of embeds. Therefore you would need to access it with `reaction.message.embeds[0]` for example. Of course if your `reaction.message.embeds`is completly empty this would not help.

A good way to check for the information is to `console.log(reaction.message)`

You can also fetch() the reaction directly to get the full MessageReaction information.

```
reaction.fetch().then((fetchedReaction) => {
    fetchedReaction.message.embeds[0]; //or
    fetchedReaction.message.embeds;
});
```

Your solution

```
reaction.message.channel.messages.fetch(reaction.message.id)
```

is indeed the best and correct way if the message may not be in the cache. This way it is still being retrived.